# Using Gson on a class that is defined into method returns null

Tags: java, json, class, null, gson

I'm have a class that i only need in one method.. so i have declared it in the method.

and now when i try to convert an object from this class to json using gson i get null.

my code is something like this:

```
private Response performGetClientDetails(HashMap<String, Object> requestMap) {

        class ClientDetails {
            String id;
            String name;
            String lastName;
            int accoundId;

            public ClientDetails(String id, String name, String lastName, int accoundId) {
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.accoundId = accoundId;
            }
        }

        ClientDetails clientDetails = new ClientDetails(client.getId(), client.getFirstName(), client.getLastName(), client.getAccount().getId());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return new Response(true, gson.toJson(clientDetails));
    }
```

what is returning `null` is this: `gson.toJson(clientDetails)` .. its supposed to return a json string.

Comment: What is null? The return of `performGetClientDetails`? Something that the `Response` class does? What does Response's constructor do with the second argument?

Comment: @mattb i have edited the post.. please have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [GSON Docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-):

"*`Gson can not deserialize {"b":"abc"} into an instance of B since the class B is an inner class. if it was defined as static class B then Gson would have been able to deserialize the string. Another solution is to write a custom instance creator for B.`* "

```
public class InstanceCreatorForB implements InstanceCreator<A.B> {
  private final A a;
  public InstanceCreatorForB(A a)  {
    this.a = a;
  }
  public A.B createInstance(Type type) {
    return a.new B();
  }
}
```

*`The above is possible, but not recommended.`*

Since you're using a non-static inner class, Gson will not be able to serialize the object.

You can try the second solution, which is not recommended, to use on your case or simply declare the `ClientDetails` class by itself, which will work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much :) i have created a class called : `JsonClasses` and placed all the inner classes i need there as inner classes. is it a good approach ??

Comment: You're welcome! Well, I don't see putting inner-classes as a good approach. This will hinder your work to declare/get information and will always have the `JsonClasses` on root of your Json response. I think that inner classes are more useful in event handlers and maybe enums.

Comment: Got it thank you! i'm new to java, so i'm trying to get how things works :)